# Size of checked in bag on Kuwait Airways?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, kuwait

The website for Kuwait Airways says the following and I find it confusing: https://www.kuwaitairways.com/en/is/free-baggage

ECONOMY
DIMENSIONS FOR NORMAL CHECKIN

Length: 90cm, width 65cm, ht 75cm

MAXIMUM DIMENSIONS

158cms/62inch

So which one is it?  Since 90cm(l) + 65cm(w) + 75cm(h) = 230cm is greater than 158cm.

Emirates on the other hand is very clear in it's statement:

The total dimensions (length + width + height) of an individual bag should not exceed 300 cm (118 inches). Bags exceeding this limit will not be accepted as checked luggage. For travel from Dammam International Airport, an individual bag should not exceed 215 cm (84.64 inches).

Answer (score 3):

> So which one is it? Since 90cm(l) + 65cm(w) + 75cm(h) = 230cm is
> greater than 158cm.

Both rules apply

1. Maximum total dimensions = 158cm when you add the lengths of the three sides.
2. No single dimension can be greater than the maximum individual lengths

This means that you can have something that's 158cm total, but it cannot be longer than 90cm and cannot be wider than 65cm, and cannot be higher than 75cm.  That doesn't mean that ALL sides can be maximum.

An example - you have something that is 65cm wide (max width) and 75cm high (max height), to fit in the maximum 158cm total the length can be no greater than 18cm (18+65+75 = 158)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  That makes a lot of sense now.  I think it would be clearer if the Kuwait website said “upto” on the lxwxh dimensions.